# AWS SKD node.js - getMetricData is not a function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have code node.js, I try to get metric data from AWS but I have error.
I have search on internet but have not any same problem.
Here is my source code:

```
function getCloudwatchMetricData(queueName, callback) {
console.log("Get CloudWatch metric data of SQS: " + queueName);
var params = {
    MetricDataQueries: [{
        Id: queueName,
        MetricStat: {
            Metric: {
                Dimensions: [{
                    Name: 'QueueName',
                    Value: queueName
                }, ],
                MetricName: 'ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible',
                Namespace: 'AWS/SQS'
            },
            Period: 300,
            Stat: 'Average',
            Unit: 'Count'
        },
        ReturnData: true
    }, ],
    StartTime: startTime,
    EndTime: endTime,
    ScanBy: 'TimestampAscending'
};
cloudwatchClient.getMetricData(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else console.log(data); // successful response
});
}
```

And here is my error:

```
TypeError: cloudwatchClient.getMetricData is not a function
at getCloudwatchMetricData (/home/baonv/cowell-project/gitlab-cowell/servertechnology/uketoru/done/53434/local.js:194:22)
at Object.exports.handler (/home/baonv/cowell-project/gitlab-cowell/servertechnology/uketoru/done/53434/local.js:313:13)
at Object._executeSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/lambda-local/lib/lambdalocal.js:136:34)
at Object._execute [as execute] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/lambda-local/lib/lambdalocal.js:39:22)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/lambda-local/bin/lambda-local:100:21
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/lambda-local/bin/lambda-local:132:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
```

I try to use AWS CLI. It's run OK
here is CLI command:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-data --metric-data-queries file://testdata/metric-data-queries.json --start-time 2018-05-20T00:00:00Z --end-time 2018-05-21T00:00:00Z --scan-by TimestampAscending
```

If have any idea or same problem, please help me.
Here is guide:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatch.html#getMetricData-property

Note: I don't want to use action "getMetricStatistics"
Thanks

Comment: Which version of the JavaScript SDK are you using? GetMetricData was released very recently, you may need the latest version to be able to use it.

Comment: I use aws-sdk version 2.175.0

Comment: GetMetricData was added in 2.221.1 https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#22211

Comment: Thank you very much.
It's running.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would check will the SDK version reference. You might be referencing to the latest documentation, but the script reference you added might be old.

Please check the version of SDK referce.

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.326.0.min.js"></script>
```